# Execute commands/code on the fly during debug mode in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

On Visual Studio while developing using ASP.NET with C# or VB, I used to be able to execute code or call some APIs on the fly using the console or debug window.

I am asking if this can be done using Eclipse while debugging JSP or Java classes, and how?

Tarek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Display view in Eclipse is used to do this. You can open using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and search for *Display*.

There, you can inspect, evaluate expressions and execute code during the current debug context. To execute code in the view for instance, you would select the code that is typed in the view and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (the same can be done by right-clicking on the selection and clicking on the appropriate option from the context menu).

Comment: Thanks. I opened the Display window, and when I type the command or API or try to enter variable name and press enter, nothing happens. Please help.

Comment: Ok Wow ! It is working. Could you please tell me why for the watch variables list in the Expressions Window, the values are Empty only while debugging JSP?